# “WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied” when running a python script

Tags: ssl, windows-7, https, python, uac

I'm getting a ["WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264502/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied-using-urllib2) when running a python script which attempts to make an https connection. The following error message is produced by python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1166, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1258, in __init__
    context = ssl._create_default_https_context()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 440, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 391, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 378, in _load_windows_store_certs
    for cert, encoding, trust in enum_certificates(storename):
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

It seems to be a permissions problem, but 1.) running the script from a command prompt with admin privileges doesn't fix the issue, and 2.) I really shouldn't have to run a script as admin to do something as basic as establish an https connection.

Any suggestions regarding how to go about addressing this problem?

Comment: Can you post the method which you use to make the connection?

Comment: @AlexH - `urllib2.urlopen('https://google.com')`